# R for loop to create a class variable taking forever

Tags: performance, r, if-statement, for-loop

My question comprises two parts. I have a matrix with IDs and several columns (representing time) of values from 0-180. I'd like to summarize these with sub groups, then compare across the columns. For example, how many IDs switch from 0-10 in column 5, to 11+ in column 6?

Now, my first thought was a SAS-style format command. This would let me group integers into different blocks (0-10,11-20,21-30,etc). But, it seems that this doesn't exist.

My solution has been to loop through all values of this matrix (dual for loops) and check whether the values fall between certain ranges(string of if statements), then enter this value into a new matrix that keeps track of only classes. Example:

```
# search through columns
for (j in 2:(dim(Tab2)[2])){ 
    # search through lines
    for (i in 1:dim(Tab2)[1]){ 
        if (is.na(Tab2[i,j])){
            tempGliss[i,j] <- "NA"}
        else if (Tab2[i,j]==0){
            tempGliss[i,j] <- "Zero"}
        else if (Tab2[i,j]>0 & Tab2[i,j]<=7){
            tempGliss[i,j] <- "1-7"}
        else if (Tab2[i,j]>=7 & Tab2[i,j]<=14){
            tempGliss[i,j] <- "7-14"}
        else if (Tab2[i,j]>=15 & Tab2[i,j]<=30){
            tempGliss[i,j] <- "15-30"}
        else if (Tab2[i,j]>=31 & Tab2[i,j]<=60){
            tempGliss[i,j] <- "31-60"}
        else if (Tab2[i,j]>=61 & Tab2[i,j]<=90){
            tempGliss[i,j] <- "61-90"}
        else if (Tab2[i,j]>=91 & Tab2[i,j]<=120){
            tempGliss[i,j] <- "91-120"}
        else if (Tab2[i,j]>=121 & Tab2[i,j]<=150){
            tempGliss[i,j] <- "121-150"}
        else if (Tab2[i,j]>=151 & Tab2[i,j]<=180){
            tempGliss[i,j] <- "151-180"}
        else if (Tab2[i,j]>180){
            tempGliss[i,j] <- ">180"}
    }
}
```

Here Tab2 is my original matrix, and tempGliss is what I'm creating as a class. This takes a VERY LONG TIME! It doesn't help that my file is quite large. Is there any way I can speed this up? Alternatives to the for loops or the if statements?

Comment: You may want to try out the `recode` function in `library(car)`, which will let you easily translate these input value ranges into categorical outputs. Since you're apply the some coding to each variable, it would be relatively easily to then use `apply(Tab2,2,recode,...)` to recode all of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `cut`

```
Tab2 <- data.frame(a = 1:9, b = c(0, 7, 14, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 155)
        ,c = c(0, 1, 7, 15, 31, 61, 91, 121, 155))
repla <- c("Zero", "1-7", "7-14", "15-30", "31-60", "61-90", "91-120", "121-150", "151-180", ">180")

for(j in 2:(dim(Tab2)[2])){
 dum <- cut(Tab2[,j], c(-Inf,0,7,14,30,60,90,120,150,180, Inf))
 levels(dum) <- repla
 Tab2[,j] <- dum
}

> Tab2
  a       b       c
1 1    Zero    Zero
2 2     1-7     1-7
3 3    7-14     1-7
4 4   15-30   15-30
5 5   31-60   31-60
6 6   61-90   61-90
7 7  91-120  91-120
8 8 121-150 121-150
9 9 151-180 151-180
```

I havent looked at it too closely but you may need to adjust the bands slightly.

Comment: This works much faster! And it skips over missing values as "NA", exactly what I wanted. Thanks a million